# How to remove inner shadow from TextField?

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I'm trying to remove the border and inner shadow of a TextField using this style:

```
.text-field {
  -fx-control-inner-background: #EEEEEE;
  -fx-background-insets: 0;
  -fx-background-color: -fx-text-box-border, -fx-control-inner-background;
}
```

And it works fine:

[image]

But when the `TextField` is focused it does show the glow effect like this:

[image]

I tried to solve it with this but it doesn't work:

```
.text-field:focused {
  -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
  -fx-focus-color: #FF5252;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update your current selector as

```
.text-field {
  -fx-control-inner-background: #EEEEEE;
  -fx-background-insets: 0;
  -fx-background-color: -fx-text-box-border, -fx-control-inner-background;
  -fx-focus-color: transparent;
}
```

which is the same as your one, I only set the `fx-focus-color` attribute.